# Como instalar e configurar o Markdown no Meteor junto com React?

Tags: node.js, meteorjs, markdown, react

Estou aprendendo React junto com Meteor, pelo que vi na documentação oficial do React o uso o Markdown é uma boa pratica contra XSS. Baixei no meteor com "meteor add markdown" mas aparentemente eu teria que configurar algo para rodar junto com o React... A documentação oficial do Meteor cita o Markdown, mas usando Blaze...  Alguma sugestão para rodar junto com React?